# Creating Array with values from console

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to create an array by taking value 'n' from the console and create an array with 'n' inits and then again take a value 'r' to work.

so far I wrote

```
int main(){
    int n = 0;
    cin >> n;
    int* a = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i< sizeof(a);i++){
       cin >> a[i];
    }
       for(int y = 0; y < sizeof(a);y++){
       cout << a[y] << " ";
       }
    int r = 0;
    cin >> r;
    rotate(a,r);
```

(the "cout" part is for checking the output of the array)

but no matter I try I would get an array which length doesn't equal the input 'n'. Can anyone give me some advice on it?

Here the outputs for every input from console:
(the second row is supposed to be the created array)

```
INPUT

6

1 2 3 4 5 6

3

OUTPUT

1 2 3 4 5 6 3 0 

INPUT

10

-1 -2 3 4 5 -6 7 -8 9 0

5

OUTPUT

-1 -2 3 4 5 -6 7 -8 

INPUT

1

1

1

OUTPUT

1 1 0 0 0 0 135137 0 


INPUT

5

1 2 3 4 5

5

OUTPUT

1 2 3 4 5 -3 135137 0
```

Any ideas why those unexplainable numbers at the end?

Comment: Tagged [c++] ==> use `std::vector` for dynamic arrays.

Comment: `sizeof` doesn't do what you think it does. It returns a size of a variable/type in bytes. In your case - 4 in 32-bit build, 8 in 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Algirdas said, take a close look at what SizeOf does. Also, you don't really need it. You can make it work like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i< n; i++){
   cin >> a[i];
}
```

As you've got 'n' elements in your array.

Also, I know that most textbooks are really fond of arrays, but please follow Cody Gray's advice!